# Want to install a custom rom (first time)

Tags: adb, fastboot, rom, redmi

I want to install custom ROM on My Redmi 7A (pine)
And I don't want to flash a recovery instead I want to use the ADB and Fastboot I unlocked my Bootloader. It is Possible?
(I am a newbie to this kind of stuff (also bad english))

Comment: 1) You can *boot* a recovery and it'll be transient instead of permanent, and 2) strictly using fastboot you can still flash GSIs, but these tend to be more buggy than device-specific ROMs.

Comment: Thanks! Andy Yan. I will still wait for more answers.

Comment: always follow the install instructions of custom ROM